# Translation "Global: Text area" in views footer

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I use Internationalization module for multilingual site.
Is there a way to translate custom text in views footer except of creating a new view for a second laguage?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP instead of text area, make the strings translatable by using t('MyString').

**Update**: usign PHP is not a recommended practice... Probably you could have a template for that view.
and inside a string inside t('My String')... Then you can use the translation interface.